# Ubuntu kernel panics / freeze after Nvidia driver installation

Tags: nvidia, kernel, freeze, nvidia-geforce

I've been running `Ubuntu 22.10` for a few months, the machine has a RTX 2080 TI GPU.

I was using the `nouveau` driver that was set by default, everything worked fine, but I needed some nvidia functionality, such as `nvidia-smi` and `cuda toolkit`.

Installing the official nvidia driver makes the OS freeze, after a minute or so when using the Desktop GUI. If I'm on tty2 terminal, the system will not freeze.

Same thing happens when installing using `apt install nvidia-driver-530`

I tried upgrading the broken system to `Ubuntu 23.04` using `do-upgrade-install` from tty2 - Same result

I clean installed `22.04 LTS` - Same result, once I install the official driver, system breaks.

With the official nvidia driver, my system will freeze, regardless of the OS version or Kernel version (6.x or 5.19.x).

```
CPU: AMD 7950X
Motherboard: Asus PRIME X670E-PRO WIFI
GPU: RTX 2080 TI
```

There's no hardware issue with the GPU, works fine under stress on Windows.

How can I diagnose / reslove the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found by brute forcing, probably not the best out there, feel free to post other solutions.

tldr, hard remove `nouveau` and `amdgpu` kernel modules.

Longer version:

Download NVIDIA official driver.
switch to runlevel 3, by running `init 3` from a terminal or from boot menu.

Remove `nouveau` driver, I also removed the `amdgpu` driver to be on the safeside - it's my motherboard onboard graphics.

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
```

`apt purge` does not actually remove the kernel modules (can be verified using lsmod after restart) - They must be blacklisted using a .conf file

```
sudo nano -w /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

set file content to:

```
blacklist amdgpu
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Now install the Nvidia driver and restart

```
sudo apt install build-essential # if you dont have gcc installed
sudo apt install libglvnd-dev # Not mandatory
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.116.03.run
init 6
```